# What is maximum of vanishing points for perspective projection?

Tags: graphics, projection, perspective, vanishing-point

I am trying to better understand the following regarding vanishing points for perspective projections:

1. Is it possible to have 4 vanishing points or more?
2. Is it possible to have infinite points?
3. Why they can have only their maximum.